# Facebook comments - Same comment everywhere on the site

Tags: facebook, comments

I've just launch a new site www.seorizon.com and I've inserted facebook connect.
When someone posts a comment, the same comment appears everywhere I've implemented the app on the site.

Is it normal?

Am I missing something?

Thank you

Mickael

Answer (score 3):

'URL to comment on' need to be unique per page, otherwise they will be glued together

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but fixed it and wrote it up here: http://records.photodharma.net/computing/facebook-comments-dynamic-urls-on-static-pages